# I would like to know why a null reference is being thrown at my simple script that works in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a simple script with a public integer named type and some collision logic.
I am then putting this script onto each cube of different colors. Each color cube has its own integer (or type) just to check whether they are the same color, and if they are not - then i destroy them both. If they do have the same type then nothing happens. The script works but throws me the NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object error. I would greatly like to know why to improve my coding. Once again this error is not stopping the game or breaking, it works. I have dropped a blue cube on a red one, and they both disappear. I have dropped a red one on a red one, and they stack. This is the behavior i desire. I simply want to know what is causing this error to improve my coding. Thank you in advance!!!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int type;

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        int xyz = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<ObjScript>().type; //line that throws error
        if (xyz != type) //comparing the two types
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us the line where the exception was throw ? You may be able to double click on your NullReferenceException in the editor. I guess it's the `GetComponent` line, 'cause if you hit a `GameObject` which does not have your `ObjScript` attached as a component, it returns null.

Comment: Done! There is an ObjScript on it, i know i should do a null check - but want to figure this out first! thanks again in advance!

Comment: This `collision.gameObject.GetComponent<ObjScript>()` assumes a whole lot. You really need to check for null. You might also use the debugger to trace through the function and see what happens.

Comment: Well i dont know any other way to refer to the script, feel free to let me know how. Furthermore, what debugger are you talking about tracing through the function - could you shed some light on that?

Comment: very simple.... the object which owns the Collision does not have a ObjctScript as part if it's components.  So this line collision.gameObject.GetComponent<ObjScript>() returns null

Comment: you can create a collision matrix to limit what can collide with what

Comment: [This gives you some tips.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) about how to debug   You can run your code step by step using the debugger. Plus, there is more docs all over the internet with `Unity Debugger`.

Comment: You are all right. I was forgetting about the plane they were initially landing on. Sorry guys :(